# (c++) saving random value from main to a function array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

so this is what i'm suppose to do but its got me kinda confused, this is what i got so far any help would be appreciated:)

Write a function that dynamically allocates an array of integers. The function should accept an integer argument indicating the number of elements to allocate and should return a pointer to the array. Then write a driver in the main function that generates a random number (something not too large), calls the function, and verifies access by saving a value to the first element and displaying the contents of that element.

edited code it runs but i feel like im not using my function at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int *MyArray(int);


int main()
{

    srand(time(0));
    int random = rand() % 5 + 1;
    const int size = 5;
    int array[size];
    MyArray(size);
   array[0] = random;
    cout << array[0] << endl;
}

int *MyArray(int numOfElements)
{
    int *array;
    array = new int[numOfElements];

    return array;
}
```

edited code

```
int main()
{

    srand(time(0));
    int random = rand() % 5 + 1;
    const int size = 5;
    int* array = MyArray(size);
    array[0] = random;
    cout << array[0] << endl;
    delete [] array;
}
```

Comment: You're nearly there... for `saving a value to the first element` you need `array[0] = random;`.  No need to call `MyArray(size);` twice either... first time the memory's leaked to no purpose.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try to explain what is your problem: why can't you do described task?

Comment: @TonyD  can you show me how it would look please I've tried entering it but just get red squiglies in places.

Comment: Because you are not restoring the return value - you have a memory leak

Comment: You deleted the wrong one! O_o.  You want `int* p = MyArray(size);` and get rid of the local `int array[size];`.  Also, if you edit the code in your question it'll confuse people reading our comments, so best to put "Updated Code" as a new section below....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you try to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int *MyArray(int);


int main()
{

    srand(time(0));
    int random = rand() % 5 + 1;
    int *array = MyArray(random); //! store the pointer of dynamically allocated memory and use it.
    array[0] = random;
    cout << array[0] << endl;
    delete [] array; //! To avoid memory leak
}

int *MyArray(int numOfElements)
{
    int *array = new int[numOfElements];
    return array;
}
```

**Note:** I'm just guessing this is what you probably looking for.